# VBA, loop column and copy cell format if value match in other column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, xls

i have an excel sheet with 2 sheets

[image: sheet 2]

what i want is to loop all rows of sheet 1(column A) and search if this value exist in 
sheet 2 column (e)['item_barcode']  if found i want to copy same highlighting to sheet2!

[image: sheet 1]

Im not good at vba in fact i never used it before, but i have to do this for my boss and this excel sheet contain more than 55k of rows ! 
is there a way it can be done with vba ? other wise i will have to
convert xls into mysql and php process it then back to xls .:D!

Comment: You don't need VBA for that. A simple vlookup() or index() should do the trick.

Comment: can you please explain more ? may be an example will be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
  Sub LoopAndHighlight()

  Dim cl As Range
  Dim RowNum As Integer

  On Error Resume Next

     For Each cl In Intersect(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange)
        RowNum = 0
        RowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cl.Value, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E:E"), 0)

        If RowNum <> 0 Then
           cl.Interior.Color = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cl.Value, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E:E"), 0)).Interior.Color
        End If
     Next cl

  End Sub
```

Comment: thanks thats really nice, but for some reason it never excuted correctly, in sheet 1 9000 rows, but when i run macro it only works on 4000 of them, and fail for the rest for some reason !

Comment: problem solved with vlookup and filter N/A then  thanks anyway

Comment: ... Weird it didn't work for more rows. Either way, glad you got it working.